# In C#, wait for browser to finish load then start a timer

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I am trying to find out how I can enable a timer and set its interval to 1000 when the webpage is finished loading.

Here is the code I've tried with so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.Navigate("website.com");
            webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("brukernavn")[0].SetAttribute("value", textBox1.Text);
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("passord")[0].SetAttribute("value", textBox2.Text);
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("login_buton")[0].InvokeMember("click");
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Interval = 7000;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("website.com/mygambling.php");
//Here I need a code to enable timer2 with interval 1000 when the website is finished loading
        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("bet")[0].SetAttribute("value", 250);
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("start")[0].InvokeMember("click");
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is how can I enable the timer2 and set timer2 interval to 1000 when the page is finished loading?

Comment: You handle [WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already know how to enable timers. The webbrowser has a [DocumentCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) event where you can subscribe to. This will help you to determine when loading of the page has finished:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("website.com/mygambling.php");
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += DocumentCompleted;
}

private void DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= DocumentCompleted;
    timer2.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: In other words, we have to subscribe to the event `DocumentCompleted` to make sure that we can manipulate `WebBrowser` 


    `webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += (object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) =>
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Document is already loaded and I can do manipulation on top of it now!");
    };`

Comment: To - Thomas Weller: why an unsubscribe is done and what is the benefit `webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= DocumentCompleted;` ?

Comment: @LJ: since I don't know what is done next, I unsubscribe from the event. This enables navigating somewhere else without enabling the timers again when the next page is loaded.